# Matlab importdata text file

Tags: matlab, text, import

I tried to import data from a text file. The data file format should be the first row are char and others are numbers, just like a xls file. But the file is generated by other software as a text file, where all data is in one row, with one space bar separated and 'tab' as a new row of data.

The data format I want to import into matlab should be like this:

```
A B C D
1 2 3 4
5 6 8 8
8 0 9 5
```

But now the data in the text file is

```
A B C D   1 2 3 4   5 6 8 8   8 0 9 5
```

How should I import the text file into the matlab in a matrix like please? I tried `importdata` but the ans is 4x1 cell. My Matlab version is 2008.

Sorry I am very new to matlab. Thank you.

Edited:
I realized that the data is

```
A B C D  1 2 3 4  5 6 8 8 8  8 0 9 5  7 0 8 8 8  5 0 9 9
```

Would you please teach me how to put these things into the cell, with one char/number one cell please?

```
   A B C D
   1 2 3 4
5  6 8 8 8
   8 0 9 5
7  0 8 8 8
   5 0 9 9
```

Coz when i use cell2mat as suggested, error msg is `CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.`

Thank you very much!

Comment: Because you have two different types (double and char), it's not possible to put everything in one matrix. That's the reason why `ìmportdata` produces a cell array.

Comment: Why are you still using the 2008 version of Matlab?

Comment: Not paying for a license are we? =P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with the cell array you generated from the text file. I call it `A`. It is a 4x1. Or maybe 1x4? With the following line we make sure that we are starting from the same point:

```
A = A(:); % make sure A is columnar
```

`A` is a cell array with the first element containing the names and from 2nd to the end containing numbers **as string.**

---

**Case 1: Consistent size of each section: Making a matrix**

Here we will see how to extract your desired matrix from this cell array.

First, we need `strread` to make a vector from a string (You can also use `textscan`):

```
v = strread(A{2})

v =

     1     2     3     4
```

Now we should apply this function on each cell and combine the vectors in a matrix. That could be achieved using `cellfun`, but since we have to first produce a cell array, at the end we will need a `cell2mat`:

```
M = cell2mat(cellfun(@strread, A(2:end), 'UniformOutput', false))
```

Here, `M` is the final result.

```
M =

     1     2     3     4
     5     6     8     8
     8     0     9     5
```

---

**Case 2: Inconsistency in the sizes + combining char / number: Making a cell array**

We want to transform the data into a cell array with each element occupying one cell. Starting from first row of `celldata` we can break the string of names into a cell array using `strsplit`:

```
celldata = strsplit(A{1});

% maximum data count in each cell of A
maxL = max(cellfun(@(x) numel(strsplit(x)), A));

% constructing an empty cell array to be filled with the data
% the importance of this step dramatically increases with the data size! 
celldata{numel(A), maxL} = [];
```

Now you can go through `celldata` and fill the cells of it with the proper values:

```
for ii = 2:numel(A)
    val = strread(A{ii});
    celldata(ii, 1:numel(val)) = num2cell(val);
end
```

`celldata` is a cell array in this form:

```
celldata = 

    'A'    'B'    'C'    'D'     []
    [1]    [2]    [3]    [4]     []
    [5]    [6]    [8]    [8]    [8]
    [8]    [0]    [9]    [5]     []
    [7]    [0]    [8]    [8]    [8]
    [5]    [0]    [9]    [9]     []
```

Comment: Thanks! Could I ask further please? coz I realized that the data in the text file is inconstant size. It was like'A B C D   1 2 3 4    5 6 9 8 8 8   8 0 9 5'. Error msg is 'CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.'

Comment: You are welcome @Cii. 2 questions: are the sizes all consistent except maybe the last one? And what do you prefer to do with the last one in that case? remove it or extend it with zeros / NaNs?

Comment: oh sorry the comment just now could not show the size of the data set. The data now is the middle set got one more data. So instead of 5,6,8,8, now it become 5,6,8,8,8. This is now 1x5 double while others are 1x4 double. Maybe I  edit my question so as to show the matrix better.